# Как отловить событеие submit через addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

пытаюсь добавить передаваемые данные при отправке формы пост собствено вот форма

```
<form id="formMenu" action="/admin/menu/menuget/create" method="post">
   <input id="menuget-key_setup" class="name" name="MenuGet[key_setup]" aria-required="true" type="text">
</form>
<a id="secures" class="btn btn-success col-lg-offset-8 col-md-offset-8 col-sm-offset-6" href="#">Сохранить меню</a>
```

для того что бы исключить веенье говнокода (отсылка формы  по ссылке и много других подванивающих моментов) хотелось бы работать с формой через addEventListener
вот скрипт отправки

```
$("#secures").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $('#formMenu').submit();}
```

пытаюсь получить отправку формы так

```
var form = document.getElementById('formMenu');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    alert('yes');
    oData = new FormData(form);
    console.log(oData);
    return false;
});
```

но форма отправляется, alert не выводится  что я делаю не так ? Jquery подключено.

Comment: **aletr** != `alert`  ошибка в обработчике `submit` прерывает исполнение кода обработчика, но не прерывает отправку формы - посмотрите ошибки в консоли браузера

Comment: А почему бы для установки обработчика не использовать метод [`.submit`](https://api.jquery.com/submit) из jQuery, раз уж она всё равно подключена — код будет более единообразен

Comment: @Igor от исправления ни чего не изменилось. в код в нес поправку

Comment: @mymedia а как ?

Comment: @Sergalas, имелось ввиду нечто вроде конструкции, которую вы уже употребили в коде: `$('#formMenu').submit(function(ev) { ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Событие формы *submit* происходит, только когда сам пользователь производит отправку. Вы же пытаетесь отправить форму из кода на JavaScript. В этом случае событие не генерируется, т.к. считается, что программист сам сделает все необходимые проверки перед вызовом метода *submit*.

Вам же следует добавить кнопку прямо в форму с помощью тега `<input type="submit">` и подходящим образом оформить её.

Но если есть маниакальное желание отправлять форму по щелчку ссылкой (надеюсь, на такой сайт я никогда не попаду), придётся дать имя функции — обработчику отправки и вызывать её из обработчика щелчка. А делать обработку отправки формы всё равно придётся, т.к. вашу форму пока можно отправить, нажав в текстовом поле клавишу ВВОДа на клавиатуре.

Пример реализации первого способа.

```js
$('#formMenu').submit(function(ev) {
        alert('yes');
        //oData = new FormData(form);
        //console.log(oData);
        return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form id="formMenu" action="/admin/menu/menuget/create" method="post">
       <input id="menuget-key_setup" class="name" name="MenuGet[key_setup]" aria-required="true" type="text">
       <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Сохранить меню">
</form>
```

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы я же говорю пытаюсь избавиться от говнокода и уже докопался до того что надо отправлять через кнопку. Есть только одно но мне нужен именно FormData надо добаить пару параметнров к post запросу